# DAX - Filter rows by evaluating the displayed columns of a table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is it possible, to filter rows of a table according to values in different columns, without knowing which columns the user chooses to display?

Here is an example to illustrate the problem:

```
A     B     C     D
---------------------
1     aaa   val   val
2     bbb
3     ccc         val
```

I would like to filter this table and show only rows that DO NOT have C and D null. In my example that would mean to display only row 1 and 3. This seems not complicated as long as I know which columns are displayed in the table. I would define a new column (not a measure) and evaluate C and D. Return "delete me" in case C and D are missing. I would then base a filter on this measure.

To make things more complicated, I want my users to be able to add columns from the datasource, according to their needs. Sticking to the example above it means that a user might add column E to the table and my "filter-measure" should not work anymore, because it doesn't consider E.

Now to my specific questions:

1. Is it possible to define a measure based on a condition like "Return 1 if columns A and B are not missing and ALL other displayed columns are missing" (without explicitly mentioning all other columns).
2. Is there a better way to achieve this? Please bear in mind, that I have to use DirectQuery, which applies some restrictions, especially in regard of PowerQuery and M.

I am not sure if it is possible to provide a solution for my problem, but since I just started with DAX I can't tell. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Warmest regards, freiaum

Comment: Are C and D an attributes Column? If not then hide this column from your model and add measures  SumC = sum(table[C]) etc. Powerbi has a function to auto-remove rows when measures return BLNAK()

Comment: I am not sure if I understand that correctly. C and D can be dates, datetimes, integers and strings - pretty much everything. In my scenario no row will ever be completely emtpy, since A and B are always "not null". So even if I change the handling of C and D, Power BI should not remove the rows because of A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here example (this is an odd concept but work for you issue) left side columns; right side AA/b as column rest as measures:

[image]

```
Sum_C = MAX(Example[C])
Sum_D = sum(Example[D])
sum_E = min(Example[E])
```

This work because if have null for C,D,E on row 2 (for example, if in C, for line 2 there is white space instead of null, that won't work anymore);